# How to log kusto query to visualize multiple dimension in one timechart?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azureportal, kql

I am a beginner to Azure portal and tried a query written down to list down some custom properties in a chart. However, I need to view the same in a timechart grouped by each custom property value (The image is attached).

```
let filterByName = 'version';
let events = dynamic(["*"]);
let mainTable = union customEvents
    | extend name =replace("\n", "", name)
    | where '*' in (events) or name in (events)
    | where iff(isempty(filterByName), 1 == 1, name contains filterByName)
    | where true;
let queryTable = mainTable;
let cohortedTable = queryTable
    | extend dimension = customDimensions["customProperty1"]
    | extend dimension = iif(isempty(dimension), "<undefined>", dimension)
    | summarize hll = hll(itemId) by tostring(dimension)
    | extend Events = dcount_hll(hll)
    | order by Events desc
    | serialize rank = row_number()
    | extend dimension = iff(rank > 5, 'Other', dimension)
    | summarize merged = hll_merge(hll) by tostring(dimension)
    | project ['version'] = dimension, Counts = dcount_hll(merged);
cohortedTable
```

I need to get an output of a timechart as shown in the image below:
[image]

I have tried the below kql log and it is not giving me the expected output.

```
| extend Version=tostring(customDimensions.distVersion)
| summarize count(Version), bin(1d,1h)
| render timechart
```

Please correct me on what I am doing wrong. Your answers to this will be a huge help for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To generate time chart, you need to project the **Timegenerated** column also along with dimension and counts columns. So that Time chart can be generated based on Timegenerated columns for each propery and respective value.

Example Query:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "K8SContainer"
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(15m)
| summarize count() by CounterName, bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| render timechart
```

Comment: The thing is, I need to get multiple charts with custom property. In the above image I attached, the two lines are 2 different custom properties of a particular event.

Comment: Do you want a separate chart for each custom property or a single chart with multiple lines (each line is a custom property)? my answer could help you to generate a single chart with multiple lines (each line is a custom property).

Comment: I have edited the question with what I have tried. That is similar to @Ramakrishna your answer but not working for me. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.